# Como ordenar alfabéticamente con struct y punteros

Tags: c, punteros, struct

Es posible ordenarlo alfabéticamente con strcompr?
Y si se puede como debería poner text.txt  para que lo ordene?
Perdón si mi pregunta es muy tonta

> void ordenar();
>       { }

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct s_txt{
    char* txt;
    int lon;
};

typedef struct
{
char * txt ;
unsigned int longitud;
}
t_texto;
typedef struct s_txt t_txt;

char* cargarStrDin(){
    int i=0;
    char letra;
    char* arr=NULL;

    letra=getche();
    if (letra!='\r'){
        arr = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char));
        if (arr==NULL){return NULL;}

        while (letra!='\r')
        {
            *(arr+i)=letra;
            i++;
            arr=(char *) realloc(arr,(i+1)*sizeof(char));
            if (arr==NULL){return NULL;}
            letra=getche();
        }
        arr[i]='\0';
    }
    printf("\n");
    return arr;

}

void imprimirTextDin(t_txt* text)
{
    FILE*arch;
    arch=fopen("frases_con_longitud.csv","w");
    fprintf(arch,"%s %d",text->txt,text->lon);
    fclose(arch);
}

t_txt cargarUnText(){
    int pos=0;
    t_txt text;
    text.txt=cargarStrDin();
    for(pos=0;text.txt!=NULL&&*((text.txt)+pos)!='\0';pos++);
    if (text.txt!=NULL){
        pos++;
    }
    text.lon=pos;
    return text;
}

t_txt* cargarTextDin(){
    int i=0;
    t_txt* text=NULL;
    t_txt auxText;
    auxText=cargarUnText();

    text=(t_txt*)malloc(sizeof(struct s_txt));
    if (text==NULL){return NULL;}

    while(auxText.txt!=NULL){
        *(text+i)=auxText;
        i++;
        text=(t_txt*)realloc(text,sizeof(struct s_txt)*(i+1));
        if (text==NULL){return NULL;}

        auxText=cargarUnText();
    }
    *(text+i)=auxText;
    return text;
}

int main()
    t_txt* text=NULL;
    text=cargarTextDin();
    ordenar(&text);
    imprimirTextDin(text);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`strcmp` es una función que permite comprar dos cadenas de texto. Lo que tienes que hacer es diseñar (o reutilizar) un algoritmo de ordenación y utilizar esta función para poder comparar los elementos de la lista.

En el caso de reutilizar algoritmos puedes recurrir a `qsort`. Esta función recibe tres parámetros:

- Puntero al inicio de al lista
- Número de elementos de la lista
- Función que permite comparar dos elementos de la lista.

Lo primero que hay que hacer es crear una función que permita comparar dos elementos de la lista:

```
int comparar(t_txt a, t_txt b)
{
  return strcmp(a.txt,b.txt);
}
```

Con esto ya podemos implementar la función `ordenar`:

```
void ordenar(t_txt* lista, int numElementos)
{
  qsort(lista, numElementos, comparar);
}
```

Y ahora actualizamos el `main`:

```
int main()
    t_txt* text=NULL;
    text=cargarTextDin();
    ordenar(text,/* ¿? */);
    imprimirTextDin(text);

    return 0;
}
```

Estoooo ¿Cuántos elementos hay en `text`? eso es algo que solo sabe `cargarTextDin`... y no lo comparte con nadie.

Esto demuestra que no has probado tu código lo más mínimo. La función `imprimirTextDin` no es capaz de funcionar correctamente porque no sabe cuántos elementos hay en la lista... luego no sabe cuándo debe parar. De hecho si revisamos la implementación de esta función vemos que únicamente trata el primer elemento de la lista... ignorando todos los demás.

Pues bien, la función `cargarTextDin` debe devolver de alguna forma el número de elementos de la lista. Esto lo puedes hacer creando una estructura nueva:

```
struct lista
{
  t_txt* elementos;
  int numElementos;
};

struct lista cargarTextDin();
```

O bien mediante un *parámetro de salida*:

```
t_txt* cargarTextDin(int* numElementos);
```

Una vez tomada la decisión (y una vez adaptada la función `cargarTextDin`) solo queda enlazar correctamente el `main`:

```
// Opción con estructura
int main()
    struct lista* lista =cargarTextDin();
    ordenar(lista);
    imprimirTextDin(lista);

    return 0;
}

void ordenar(struct lista* lista);
void imprimirTextDin(struct lista* lista);

// Mediante argumento de salida
int main()
    int numElementos;
    t_txt* text=cargarTextDin(&numElementos);
    ordenar(text,numElementos);
    imprimirTextDin(text,numElementos);

    return 0;
}
```

Eso sí, nota que en cualquier caso te falta una función para liberar la memoria reservada.